The custom lazy model does not paginate properly
I have a problem with my custom lazy model. The first time I enter the xhtml page, the pagination buttons are not enabled, but if I sort by the case column, for example, the pagination is enabled and works fine. What is this due to? I am using native queries to build the model, and it extracts the data well, but I don't understand why it won't paginate the data if I don't sort by column. Please help. Thank you.
my xhtml:
        <p:dataTable var="expediente"
                        value="#{peticionesPendientesBean.lazyModel}"
                        rowKey="#{expediente.mCodExpediente}"
                        sortBy="#{expediente.t1.id_expediente}" sortOrder="UNSORTED" paginator="true"                                           
                        rows="10"
                        styleClass="desplegable"
                        paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} 0 Seleccionados {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown} "
                        rowsPerPageTemplate="10,20,50,100,200"
                        id="tblPendientes" lazy="true" emptyMessage="#{msg.tbl_noRegist}"
                        currentPageReportTemplate="#{peticionesPendientesBean.lazyModel.rowCount==1? lbl.tb_exp_pag : lbl.tb_exps_pag}">                                       
                                    
                        <p:column headerText="#{lbl.titulo_peticiones_pendientes}"
                            sortBy="#{expediente.id_expediente}" id="codExpediente">
                            <h:outputText
                            value="#{expediente.getAtributo(nombreAtributos.CODEXPEDIENTE).value} " />
                        </p:column>

/**
 * @param first
 * @param pageSize
 * @param sortField
 * @param sortOrder
 * @param filters
 */
@Override
public List<Expediente> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder,
        Map<String, Object> filters) {

    try {
        System.out.println("usuario" + user.getCentroDirectivo().getCodCentro());
        System.out.println("perfil" + user.getRole());
        System.out.println("peticionesPendientes: " + peticionesPendientes);
        System.out.println("user: " + user);

        if (sortField == null || sortOrder.equals(SortOrder.UNSORTED)) {
            sortField = "id_expediente"; 
            sortOrder = SortOrder.DESCENDING;
        }

        this.dataSource = this.peticionesPendientes.buscarPendientesNativa(user.getCentroDirectivo().getCodCentro(),
                user.getRole(), first, pageSize, sortField, sortOrder);
        System.out.println("datasource" + dataSource.size());
        
        int count = portaFirmaEnvios.buscarPendientesNativaCount(user.getCentroDirectivo().getCodCentro(),
                user.getRole());
        if (count == 0) {
            this.setRowCount(0);
        } else {
            this.setRowCount(count);
        }
        
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        final FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        context.addMessage(Cadenas.EVENT,
                new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, Presentacion.ERROR_MSG, ERR.getString("error_con_motor")));
        dataSource = new ArrayList<Expediente>();
        this.setRowCount(dataSource.size());

        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage() + e.getCause(), e);
    }
    return dataSource;
}


Please provide a [mcve]. For example, what PF version are you using? Where is your @Override public int count(Map<String, FilterMeta> filterBy) method? See http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/lazy.xhtml

I'm using Primefaces 5.3, I haven't a method called @Override public int count(Map<String, FilterMeta> filterBy) method.

I'm using java 7 version too

Please consider upgrading to the current version of PF. There were some improvements and fixes regarding this. In older versions (I think before 10), you would need to set the row count initially.

Does this answer your question? How to query data for Primefaces dataTable using lazy loading and pagination
